# How can I write my own aggregate functions with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, aggregate-functions

How can I write my own aggregate functions with SQLAlchemy? As an easy example I would like to use numpy to calculate the variance. With sqlite it would look like this:

```
import sqlite3 as sqlite
import numpy as np

class self_written_SQLvar(object):
  def __init__(self):
    import numpy as np
    self.values = []
  def step(self, value):
    self.values.append(value)
  def finalize(self):
    return np.array(self.values).var()

cxn = sqlite.connect(':memory:')
cur = cxn.cursor()
cxn.create_aggregate("self_written_SQLvar", 1, self_written_SQLvar)
# Now - how to use it:
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE 'mytable' ('numbers' INTEGER)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO 'mytable' VALUES (1)") 
cur.execute("INSERT INTO 'mytable' VALUES (2)") 
cur.execute("INSERT INTO 'mytable' VALUES (3)") 
cur.execute("INSERT INTO 'mytable' VALUES (4)")
a = cur.execute("SELECT avg(numbers), self_written_SQLvar(numbers) FROM mytable")
print a.fetchall()
>>> [(2.5, 1.25)]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The creation of new aggregate functions is backend-dependant, and must be done 
directly with the API of the underlining connection. SQLAlchemy offers no 
facility for creating those.

However after created you can just use them in SQLAlchemy normally.

Example:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Table, create_engine, MetaData, Integer
from sqlalchemy import func, select
from sqlalchemy.pool import StaticPool
from random import randrange
import numpy
import sqlite3

class NumpyVarAggregate(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.values = []
  def step(self, value):
    self.values.append(value)
  def finalize(self):
    return numpy.array(self.values).var()

def sqlite_memory_engine_creator():
    con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    con.create_aggregate("np_var", 1, NumpyVarAggregate)
    return con

e = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True, poolclass=StaticPool,
                  creator=sqlite_memory_engine_creator)
m = MetaData(bind=e)
t = Table('mytable', m, 
            Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
            Column('number', Integer)
          )
m.create_all()
```

Now for the testing:

```
# insert 30 random-valued rows
t.insert().execute([{'number': randrange(100)} for x in xrange(30)])

for row in select([func.avg(t.c.number), func.np_var(t.c.number)]).execute():
    print 'RESULT ROW: ', row
```

That prints (with SQLAlchemy statement echo turned on):

```
2009-06-15 14:55:34,171 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...d20c PRAGMA 
table_info("mytable")
2009-06-15 14:55:34,174 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...d20c ()
2009-06-15 14:55:34,175 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...d20c 
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    number INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
2009-06-15 14:55:34,175 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...d20c ()
2009-06-15 14:55:34,176 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...d20c COMMIT
2009-06-15 14:55:34,177 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...d20c INSERT
INTO mytable (number) VALUES (?)
2009-06-15 14:55:34,177 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...d20c [[98], 
[94], [7], [1], [79], [77], [51], [28], [85], [26], [34], [68], [15], [43], 
[52], [97], [64], [82], [11], [71], [27], [75], [60], [85], [42], [40], 
[76], [12], [81], [69]]
2009-06-15 14:55:34,178 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...d20c COMMIT
2009-06-15 14:55:34,180 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...d20c SELECT
avg(mytable.number) AS avg_1, np_var(mytable.number) AS np_var_1 FROM mytable
2009-06-15 14:55:34,180 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...d20c []
RESULT ROW: (55.0, 831.0)
```

Note that I didn't use SQLAlchemy's ORM (just the sql expression part of SQLAlchemy was used) but you could use ORM just as well.

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is a really very nice and good answere!

Comment: Can any reference from the docs or whatever? If you have one. @nosklo

Answer (score -1):

at first you have to import func from sqlalchemy

you can write

func.avg('fieldname')

or func.avg('fieldname').label('user_deined')

or you can go thru for mre information

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/ormtutorial.html#using-subqueries

Comment: This works fine with standard aggregate functions like avg or count. But the question is how to treat self implemented aggregate functions. By the way, the tutorial seems to be quite nice. Thanx for the link.