# How to create custom aggregate functions using SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, python-3.6, aggregate-functions, sqlalchemy-utils

SQLAlchemy 1.4 ORM using an AsyncSession, Postgres backend, Python 3.6

I am trying to create a custom aggregate function using the `SQLAlchemy ORM`. The SQL query would look something like:

```
COUNT({group_by_function}),{group_by_function} AS {aggregated_field_name)}
```

I've been searching for information on this.

I know this can be created internally within the `Postgres` db first, and then used by `SA`, but this will be problematic for the way the codebase I'm working with is set up.

I know `SQLAlchemy-Utils` has [functionality](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aggregates.html) for this, but I would prefer not to use an external library.

The most direct [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996922/how-can-i-write-my-own-aggregate-functions-with-sqlalchemy) on this topic I can find says "The creation of new aggregate functions is backend-dependant, and must be done directly with the API of the underlining connection." But this is from quite a few years ago and thought there might have been updates since.

Am I missing something in the `SA ORM` docs that discusses this or is this not supported by `SA`, full stop?

Answer (score 1):

you can try something this query

```
query = db.session.query(Model)\
    .with_entities(
        Model.id, 
        func.sum(Model.number).label('total_sum')
    ).group_by(Model.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I am going to try to implement this.

Comment: I am using an Async Engine Session with the SA ORM and, depending on how I try to connect this to the existing query, the suggested query errors with `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'with_entities'` OR `AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'with_entities'` OR `AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'func'`.                      Any ideas on how to use this code with an `Async select` type of query?